# Escoger al azar un valor y presentar su probabilidad

Tags: r, rstudio

me gustaría saber dada una Base de Datos poblacional, cómo se escoge la ciudad al azar de X país y después la probabilidad de que esa ciudad tenga una población superior a X en X año.

No sé ni por donde empezar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenida Irene a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor agrega más información a tu pregunta, ejemplo de los datos que estás hablando, lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora. Suerte.